# Qual a forma correta de chamar métodos em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Qual a forma correta de se fazer uma chamada de método no Python? Como no exemplo abaixo.

```
def __init__(self):
   mtd([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])

def mtd(data):
   for value in data:
       print(value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro da classe deves colocar `self`, equivalente ao `$this` em PHP, ou `this` em Java na chamada de um metodo, mas tem uma particularidade, é que é definida que entra como argumento também no metodo chamado, ex:

```
class Hey():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mtd([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]) # indicas que e um metodo interno da class

    def mtd(self, data):
        for value in data:
            print(value)

hey = Hey()
```

Não consigo perceber bem na pergunta, mas se for um metodo externo à class, fazes como estavas a fazer:

```
class Hey():
    def __init__(self):
        mtd([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])

def mtd(data):
    for value in data:
        print(value)

hey = Hey()
```

Answer (score 3):

Em Python, todo método referente a uma classe precisa ser referenciado, no primeiro parâmetro, pela pseudo-variável `self`.

```
def __init__(self):
   self.mtd([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])

def mtd(self, data):
   for value in data:
       print(value)
```

O `self` portanto indica que `mtd` pertence à classe que a contém.