# Por que temos que utilizar o atributo self como argumento nos métodos?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Assisti a uma video aula onde é dito que todo método é obrigado a passar o parâmetro `self` na definição do método, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
        self._real = real
        self._imag = imag
```

Este exemplo retirei [daqui](http://wiki.python.org.br/ProgramacaoOrientadaObjetoPython). A única explicação que achei nessa página foi esta. Mas não entendi o que o autor quis dizer.

> O primeiro argumento do método é sempre referenciado no início do
>   processo. Por convenção, o primeiro argumento do método tem sempre o
>   nome self. Portanto, os atributos de self são atributos de instância
>   da classe.

Em Java, que é uma linguagem com a qual já sou familiarizado não há essa necessidade. Alguém sabe o porquê dessa obrigação em Python?

Comment: Ainda ontem foi respondido isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176250/qual-a-forma-correta-de-chamar-m%C3%A9todos-em-python/176252#176252 , a resposta do Wallace explica isso

Comment: [***Dá uma olha no site do Pedro Werneck***](http://www.pedrowerneck.com/o-porque-do-self-explicito-em-python-pt-br.html)

Comment: @Miguel Obrigado pela refência. Apesar de a resposta do Wallace ser correta, achei meio superficial. Eu gostaria de entender a necessidade real, o motivo além de dizer que pertence ao método. Já que em outras linguagens não há essa necessidade.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway obrigado, parece ser uma ótima referência. Lerei com calma logo mais. Se ngm tiver respondido tentarei elaborar uma resposta com base no que aprendi e postar aqui.

Comment: Se te ajudar, coloca suas conclusões sobre sua pergunta aqui mesmo como resposta e marque suas considerações como resposta, por favor. Assim vai ajudar quem tiver a mesma dúvida e a pergunta vai ficar como respondida. Além disso teremos o começo de uma documentação para o problema (acho que esse é o objetivo).

Comment: Relacionado: ['Há alguma vantagem num “self” explícito em vez do “this” implícito?'](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4873/215)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Apenas uma convenção para deixar explícito a instância do objeto dentro da classe.

O autor da linguagem [define (na pergunta 4.21)](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/python-faq/part1/) `self` da seguinte forma:

> Self is merely a conventional name for the first argument of a
> method -- i.e. a function defined inside a class definition.  A method
> defined as meth(self, a, b, c) should be called as x.meth(a, b, c) for
> some instance x of the class in which the definition occurs;
> the called method will think it is called as meth(x, a, b, c).

Eu vou criar uma história fictícia que é apenas uma brincadeira para ilustrar e tentar dar um entendimento que faça mais sentido que apenas uma convenção como é explicado pelo autor.

Suponha que eu queira escrever várias funções comuns para um certo objeto, que no caso do Python pode ser um dicionário simples.
Dessa forma, ao chamar cada função que eu escrevi, teria que passar para essa função esse objeto e em seguida os parâmetros propriamente da função. Exemplo:

```
item = {'qt': 10, 'nome': 'Banana', 'preco': 12.20}

def Desconto(objeto, percentual):
  objeto['preco'] = objeto['preco'] * (percentual / 100.0)
```

E para chamar a função:

```
Desconto(item, 10)
```

Vamos dizer que eu monte uma série de funções que trabalham em cima do mesmo tipo de objeto. Podemos dizer que eu criei uma **classe** de funções. Para efeito de organização vamos convencionar que o nome das funções passam a ser `NomeDaClasse.NomeDaFunção(Objeto, Param1, Param2, ...)`.
Eu teria algo do tipo:

```
def MinhaClasse.Funcao1(Objeto, Param1, Param2, ...)
   ...
def MinhaClasse.Funcao2(Objeto, Param1, Param2, ...)
   ...
def MinhaClasse.Funcao3(Objeto, Param1, Param2, ...)
   ...
```

Agora, sempre que eu quiser chamar uma função basta identificar a classe e saber que o primeiro parâmetro sempre é um objeto de um certo tipo que aquela classe de funções entende.

Se eu convencionar que no meu código fonte eu posso escrever esse conjunto de funções de uma forma diferente, por exemplo, para não repetir o nome da classe no nome da função, vou colocar assim:

```
class NomeDaClasse ()
   def Funcao1(Objeto, Param1, Param2, ...)
     ...
   def Funcao2(Objeto, Param1, Param2, ...)
     ...
```

Quando eu quiser chamar a função dessa classe, eu continuaria a fazer:

```
NomeDaClasse.NomeDaFuncao(Objeto, Param1, Param2, ...)
```

Só que como eu criei um jeito bem parecido com a estrutura de classes da **OO**, então eu poderia dar um jeito de criar uma forma de passar os atributos do meu objeto em um inicializador, que eu também vou convencionar com um nome bem diferente, por exemplo, `__init__` e através dele eu passo os valores dos atributos do meu "objeto" e crio uma única instância dessa classe. Tudo vai ficar muito parecido com as classes e objetos da **OO**.

Eu também vou convencionar que posso chamar as funções do meu objeto com uma sintaxe mais simples, por exemplo:

```
MeuObjeto.MinhaFuncao(Param1, Param2, ...)
```

Como eu simplifiquei tudo mas não quero que o programador saiba que tem coisas implícitas nessas minhas convenções, vou manter na assinatura das funções dentro da classe um nome especial, que vou chamar de `self` para indicar o parâmetro que é o objeto da minha classe. Ao fazer a chamada, internamente meu compilador faria o seguinte:

```
MeuObjeto.MinhaFuncao(...) => MinhaClasse.MinhaFuncao(MeuObjeto, ...)
```

Assim eu facilitei para o programador que pode usar uma sintaxe bem parecida com a sintaxe da **OO** e vou deixar explícito para essas convenções que eu fiz, deixando o nome `self` dentro da assinatura dos métodos da classe.

Comment: Python tem classes e orientação a objeto desde o início - o primeiro release público, versão 0.9.0, em 1991 já era OOP

Comment: @jsbueno Você tem razão vou editar a resposta para remover isso e colocar a definição do que é "self" pelo próprio autor da linguagem e deixar mais claro que a analogia que eu criei é fictícia.

Answer (score 13):

Se você seguir o [Zen do Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3) você verá que em Python: *Explícito é melhor que implícito*. E isso é levado muito a sério em toda a linguagem e em todas propostas de novidades para ela.

Da mesma forma que você precisa passar `self` nos métodos de instância, você também não pode omitir o `self.` quando acessa os métodos ou variáveis de instância. Você pode enxergar isso também pela lógica oposta: linguagens como Java e C# inventaram essa palavra reservada `this` que nada mais é do que um argumento escondido para uma função que foi declarada como *método*, representando o objeto atual.

Essas escolhas no design da linguagem Python possibilitaram não ser necessário criar uma palavra reservada para representar esse argumento implícito dentro dos métodos. Desta forma os métodos funcionam exatamente igual a todas as outras funções. Inclusive você não precisa chamar o primeiro argumento `self`. Pode ser o que você quiser.

Depois dê uma lida na [história por trás da sintaxe de classes](http://python-history.blogspot.in/2009/02/adding-support-for-user-defined-classes.html).

Comment: +1 para o The Zen of Python

Answer (score 7):

A princípio `self` é apenas um [parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) como outro qualquer. Nele você recebe um objeto e depois através dessa variável, afinal todo parâmetro também é uma variável, você acessará os membros desse objeto.

O que tem de diferente na linguagem é que na chamada do método há um tratamento para o objeto ser passado como esse parâmetro.

Pense que métodos não existem de fato, o que existe é uma função com um primeiro parâmetro que é especial. Esse parâmetro sempre recebe o nome de `self`.

Então se tivermos uma classe chamada `Classe` e uma instância dessa classe for chamada assim

```
objeto.metodo()
```

na verdade é

```
Classe_metodo(objeto)
```

`objeto` é o argumento que está sendo passado e o parâmetro `self` em `metodo()` irá receber essa instância. O truque da linguagem só ocorre no que foi demonstrado acima, o resto é tudo igual.

```
class Classe(object):
    propriedade = 0
    def metodo(self):
        print(self.propriedade) #se tiver só propriedade aqui seria uma variavel local
        
objeto = Classe()
objeto.propriedade = 10
objeto.metodo()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/A0rOP5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/phjifhke-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/SelfExplained.py).

Note que `self` é uma convenção que todo bom *pythonista* segue, mas na verdade você poderia colocar o que quisesse de nome do primeiro parâmetro do método, `this`, `obj`, `abobrinha`, etc.