# O que significa esse ponto "." em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operadores, sintaxe

O que significa esse **ponto** entre a variável `var` e `index`?

**Exemplo:**

```
 var = ['João','Pedro','André','Alice']
 var.index('André')
```

**Tem algum nome?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É o *dot operator* ou operador de ponto. Ele é o operador que dá acesso a membros do objeto contido na variável. Esses membros podem ser variáveis ou métodos do objeto.

Então nesse caso `var` é um objeto de lista. Uma lista possui alguns métodos, um deles é o `index()`. Então você está acessando o método `index()` contido na classe de lista e ele será aplicado ao objeto contido em `var`.

Se já viu como se cria um método na classe sabe que o primeiro parâmetro dele deve ser o [`self`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176543/101) que é o parâmetro que receberá este objeto que está antes do ponto.

```
var.index('André')
```

é o equivalente a se escrever uma função assim:

```
index(var, 'André')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/Sugar.py).

Comment: Entendi! Isso é valido pra funções também caso eu queira acessar uma var, ou são casos diferentes?

Comment: Isso é válido para métodos apenas.