# Notação de ponto em python ( métodos )

Tags: python, método

Como se cria métodos do tipo notação de ponto, aqueles que são chamados `object.show ()` em vez de `show ( objec )`, ou eles se aplicam apenas a strings, se sim por que exatamente ?

Comment: Você tem conhecimento sobre o paradigma de orientação a objetos?

Comment: veja se te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199737/101

Comment: Sim Anderson, e depois de postar pensei que a galera ia pensar mesmo em uma chamada normal de um objeto - claro pensando que tudo da linguagem são ' objetos ', porém perguntei com outro intuito.

Comment: E qual seria esse outro intuito? Acho que ele não ficou muito claro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A notação de ponto em Python é usada para recuperar atributos de objetos.  Em particular em Python, não há uma distinção no momento em que você usa o ponto entre um "atributo" e um "método" - como em Python tudo é um objeto e o que distingue os métodos é que eles são membros "chamáveis" ("callable") de um objeto.

Então, para criar um método, a forma mais comum é  criar uma classe, e definir os métodos dentro do corpo da classe com a notação `def <nome>
 (self, [parametro, ...]):`  - exatamente como fazemos com funções soltas. Depois disso, ao serem criadas instâncias dessa class, os métodos estarão disponíveis:

```
class A:
    def b(self):
         print(f"Método b chamado no objeto {self}")

a = A()
a.b()
```

se você colar iso no modo intertivo (Python 3.6) a saída será algo como:

```
Método b chamado no objeto <__main__.A object at 0x7f19d24b77b8>
```

(Para versões de Python entre 3.0 e 3.5, remova a "f-string" e use o método ".format").

Há outras formas de se colocar atributos recuperáveis por ponto - por exemplo a simples atribuição - que pode ser feita tanta na classe quanto em alguma instância de objeto. Continuando o exemplo acima:

```
def bla():
   print("bla chamado")

a.bla = bla

a.bla()
```

Desta vez a função "a" se torna um atributo da instância `a` do objeto da classe `A` que criamos. A maior diferença sendo que desta forma ela não recebe uma referência à própria instância de forma automática (veja, a função `bla` foi definida sem o parâmetro `self` e daria erro se fosse delcarada com `self` e usada dessa forma).

As regras que o Python usa para acesaruma tributo de instância ou de classe - e quando ele acrescenta automaticamente o atributo `self` ou não - são bem definidas na linguagem. - mas requerem um certo estudo para serem entendidas em sua totalidade, por que cobrem todos os *corner cases*. Para uso no dia a dia costumam ser intuitivas o suficiente. O [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) talvez seja o melhor documento para entender a linguagem como um todo e essas regras.

Um resumo simplificado só para entender o mais básico da busca de atributos - após o ponto há um nome de atributo, e o Python runtime busca o atributo no objeto seguindo esses passos:

- O método `__getattribute__` do objeto é chamado com os parâmetros `self` e o nome do atributo. Via de regra, as classes definidas em código "do dia a dia" não redefinem o método `__getattribute__` - então esse método está na base da hierarquia de objetos do Python - e procede à busca do atributo. Os próximos passos na verdade ocorrem *dentro*  desse `__getattribute__` padrão. O primeito dos casos abaixo que der "match" é retornado como o atributo:
- O Python busca na classe e superclasse do objeto se o atributo existe e é um objeto do tipo "data-descriptor" (um objeto que por sua vez tenha o método `__get__`  E um dentre `__set__` ou `__del__`) - eu não vou detalhar o que acontece se ele encontra para manter esta resposta num nível intermediário. Só adianto que quando usamos o decorator `@property` ele cai nesse caso.
- Caso não encontre um descritor, o Python olha no atributo `__dict__` da própria instância se existe uma chave com aquele nome. S
- O Python busca na classe do objeto por um atributo com aquele nome.
- Se não encontrar na classe, ele procura nas superclasses, seguindo a ordem que está no atributo `.__mro__` da classe.
- Se não for encontrado ainda, o Python chama o método `__getattr__` (é difernete do `__getattribute__`) da classe, assando o nome do atributo.
- Se a chamada ao  `__getattr__` falhar, acontece uma exceção `AttributeError` e o atributo não é recuperado.

Além disso vale a pena acrescentar que para objetos cujas classes são definidas direto em C, usando a Python API, e não em Python puro, em geral não é possível acrescentar novos atributos ou métodos dinâmicamente. Ou seja, você não pode pendurar novos métodos nas classes `str` ou `int` do Python, como é possível em Ruby.

Comment: Resposta esplêndida, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos começar com um exemplo em que são criados 4 métodos, sendo um `init`, os dois primeiros com a notação show(obj) e o último com a chamada que que vc chama de 'notação de ponto'.

[Veja o código apresentado nessa resposta, rodando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/ImlY)

```
class collection1::
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

    # Tamanho da collection (função len) 
    def __len__(self):    
        return len(self.lst)

    # Fornece a posição de um item na collection
    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self.lst[position]

    # Apresenta a collection 
    def show(self):
        print (self.lst)
```

---

Agora vamos instanciar e executar os metodos:

```
c = collection1()
print (len(c))
5

print (c[3])
4

c.show()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Métodos com nomes iniciados e terminados com `__` (dunderscore)** 
 
São os métodos especias, chamados por alguns de "métodos mágicos", a principal coisa que vc deve saber sobre esses métodos é que voce não deve chama-los diretamente (embora isso possa ser feito). Ao invés de usar `obj.__len__()` ou `obj.__getitem__[3]` deve-se usar `len(obj)` e `obj[3]`. Note que se *obj* é um tipo 'embutido' (built-in), como list, str, etc. O interpretador fará uma chamada a uma função (que pode estar em cpython) através de um atalho. Se a classe da qual *obj* é uma instancia, foi implementada por voce, o interpretador chamará o método de instancia que voce implementou, no caso `__getitem__` e/ou `__len__`.

**Porque len não é um método?** 
 
Luciano Ramalho em seu livro [Python Fluente](https://www.novatec.com.br/livros/pythonfluente/), afirma que fez essa pergunta a um dos "core developers" em 2013 e a chave da resposta foi uma citação de [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) 'praticality beats purity' (A praticidade supera a pureza). Recomendo o livro (não, não estou ganhando nada. :-) ) para maiores detalhes.

**Implementando nosso própio `str` na nossa classe:** 
 
Vamos supor que precisassemos ou quisessemos implementar um str "metido a besta" na nossa classe, teriamos apenas que implementar `__str__`, assim:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Classe especial com uma lista simples'
```

Agora poderiamos usar a função `str` como se fosse uma função embutida no python, a diferença é que o interpretador vai chamar a nossa função:

```
obj = collection1()
print (obj)
Classe especial com uma lista simples
```

**Conclusão**
 
A não ser pelas implementações dos [métodos escpeciais](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames), a maioria dos métodos que voce desenvolver, serão do tipo que voce chama de "notação de ponto", aliás, mesmo os métodos especiais tem a mesma implementação (que os da tal notação) a diferença está somente na chamada e na mágica.

[DEMO](https://repl.it/ImlY)

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pela resposta e indicação do livro

Comment: Vale a pena colocar que os métodos mágicos são sempre começados *e* terminados com `__` -  por que o efeito  de um nome de método só começado com `__` é completamente diferente (aí entra o mecanismo de name-mangling)

Comment: Verdade, coloquei iniciados com dunderscores mas, na realidade é: inicidados e terminados. Vou editar. Obrigado.

Comment: E extra oficialmente são chamados por métodos dunder, por exemplo: `__len__` é o *dunder len*, assim como `__x__` seria o *dunder x*. Apenas uma curiosidade que vale o comentário.