# Como acessar um atributo privado em uma classe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Escreva um programa de bancos que possua:

```
Uma classe Banco com os atributos
- private total
- public TaxaReserva
- private reservaExigida

E métodos
- public podeFazerEmprestimo(valor) --> bool
- public MudaTotal(valor)
```

E uma classe conta com os atributos
    - private saldo
    - private ID
    - private senha

```
E métodos
- public deposito(senha, valor)
- public saque(senha, valor)
- public podeReceberEmprestimo(valor) --> bool
- public saldo --> float
```

SOlução:

```
        class Banco(object):
    __total =10000
    TaxaReserva = 0.1
    __reservaExigida = __total*TaxaReserva
    def podeFazerEmprestimo(self,valor):
        if self.__saldo >= 1000:
            return True

    def MudaTotal(self,valor):
        Banco.__total += valor
        return Banco.__total





class Conta(Banco):
    def __init__(self,saldo,ID,senha):

        self.__saldo = saldo
        self.__ID = ID
        self.__senha = senha

    def deposito(self,senha, valor):
        Conta.__saldo += valor

    def saque(self,senha, valor):
        if (senha == self.__senha) and (valor <= self.__saldo) :
            self.__saldo -= valor
    def podeReceberEmprestimo(self,valor):
        pass

    def saldo(self):
        return self.__saldo

##    def __call__(self,x):  # torna a instância callable!
##        return x




itau = Conta(1000,123456,"POO")
itau.saque("POO",200)
print(itau.saldo())
#print(callable(itau)) #é instancia! não é callable! exceto se criar  __call__
#print(callable(Conta))# é callable!
#print(callable(itau)) se criar o def __call___, torna-se callable!
print(Banco.total)
```

itau = Conta(1000,123456,"POO")
itau.saque("POO",200)

Como acessar o atributo senha? Eu recebo o erro:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Conta' has no attribute '_Conta__senha'
```

Comment: tenta `def saque(self, senha, valor):`, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176543/5749

Comment: "Python não é Java": evite o uso de atributos "privados" com prefixo de  "__": eles só vão complicar sua vida. Em termos de linguagem todos os atributos são públicos - você pode usar um único "_" para indicas a usuários da suas classes (isso é outros programadores que vão usar as mesmas) que os atributos são privados, e isso é feito por convenção. O uso de "__" ativa uma funcionalidade de name-mangling que na verdade tem utilidade bem restrita.

Comment: @jsbueno: obrigado! Fiz apenas para entender como funciona! Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Banco(object):
    __total =10000
    TaxaReserva = 0.1
    __reservaExigida = __total*TaxaReserva
    def podeFazerEmprestimo(self,valor):
        if self.__saldo >= 1000:
            return True

    def MudaTotal(self,valor):
        Banco.__total += valor
        return Banco.__total

    def get_total(self):
        return Banco.__total





class Conta(Banco):
    def __init__(self,saldo,ID,senha):

        self.__saldo = saldo
        self.__ID = ID
        self.__senha = senha

    def deposito(self,senha, valor):
        Conta.__saldo += valor

    def saque(self,senha, valor):
        if (senha == self.__senha) and (valor <= self.__saldo) :
            self.__saldo -= valor
    def podeReceberEmprestimo(self,valor):
        pass

    def saldo(self):
        return self.__saldo

##    def __call__(self,x):  # torna a instância callable!
##        return x


itau = Conta(1000,123456,"POO")
itau.saque("POO",200)
print(itau.saldo())
#print(callable(itau)) #é instancia! não é callable! exceto se criar  __call__
#print(callable(Conta))# é callable!
#print(callable(itau)) se criar o def __call___, torna-se callable!
#print(Banco.total) # da erro
print(Banco._Banco__total) #acessar variaveis privadas em Python através da sintaxe _NomeDaClasse__nomeDaVariavel
print("Total",itau.get_total())
```

Answer (score 3):

Olá,

Altere seu método saque. Troque Conta por self:

```
def saque(self,senha, valor):
    if (senha == self.__senha) and (valor <= self.__saldo) :
        self.__saldo -= valor
```

Comment: poderia explicar? Não entendi bem o porquê!

Comment: Claro! Este é um método que altera os atributos do próprio objeto (por isso você utiliza o self).
"Conta" é apenas o nome da sua classe, enquanto o self se trata do objeto que chamou este método (objeto "itau" no seu caso)

Comment: agora o erro é no Banco.total, que é privado: "AttributeError: type object 'Banco' has no attribute 'total'"