# Como declarar e usar métodos que estão na mesma classe

Tags: python

Boa tarde. Gostaria de saber como é feito a declaracao e a utilizacao de métodos dentro da mesma classe. Por exemplo, em uma classe há 2 métodos, a qual 1 método utiliza o outro.

Por exemplo:

```
class ClasseEMetodo:
    def retorna_valor:
        return '10'

    def imprimi_valor:
        print('O valor é {0}' retorna_valor())


# chamada
var = ClasseEMetodo
var.imprimi_valor()
```

O erro mostrado é:

```
    def retorna_valor:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Basicamente https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176543/por-que-temos-que-utilizar-o-atributo-self-como-argumento-nos-m%C3%A9todos , e no teu caso tens mais uns erros de sintaxe à mistura: https://repl.it/repls/StarryIndianredOs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ClasseEMetodo:
    @classmethod
    def retorna_valor(cls):
        return '10'

    @classmethod
    def imprimi_valor(cls):
        print('O valor é {0}'.format(cls.retorna_valor()))


# chamada
var = ClasseEMetodo
var.imprimi_valor()  # O valor é 10
```

Comment: O que é o (cls)?

Comment: `cls` -- `ClasseEMetodo`. `print(cls)  # <class '__main__.ClasseEMetodo'>`, `print(ClasseEMetodo)  # <class '__main__.ClasseEMetodo'>`