# Código de Fila em Python - Como verificar se existe um elemento com nome específico na fila e a sua posição do index?

Tags: python, fila

Estou fazendo um código de fila de um banco onde é preciso digitar o **nome, idade, peso e gênero** de classe **Pessoa** e classe **Fila** e esse código tem algumas opções que devem ser inseridas de acordo com o vontade do usuário. (Aparentemente o código funciona)

Eu queria saber como fazer com que esse código em fila **permita que haja uma verificação se um nome específico do elemento está na fila e mostre o índex de onde o nome está?**

a linha de código está em `elif opcao == 6:`

```
# Código de fila
class Fila:
    inicio = None
    fim = None

class Pessoa:
    nome: str
    idade: int
    peso: float
    genero: str
    proximo = None

def inserir_elemento(fila, pessoa):
    if fila_vazia(fila):
        fila.inicio = pessoa
        fila.fim = pessoa
    else:
        fila.fim.proximo = pessoa
        fila.fim = pessoa
    print(f"Elemento {pessoa.nome} foi inserido\n")

def excluir_elemento(fila):
    if fila_vazia(fila) == True:
        print("A fila está vazia")
    else:
        elemento_excluido = fila.inicio
        proximo_fila = fila.inicio.proximo
        del fila.inicio
        fila.inicio = proximo_fila
        if fila.inicio == None:
            fila.fim = None
        print(f"O elemento ({elemento_excluido.nome}) foi excluído\n")

def fila_vazia(fila):
    verificar_fila = (fila.inicio == None and fila.fim == None)
    return verificar_fila

def tamanho_fila(fila):
    if (fila_vazia(fila) == True):
        return 0
    else:
        contador_fila = 0
        ver_pessoa = fila.inicio
        while ver_pessoa != None:
            contador_fila += 1
            ver_pessoa = ver_pessoa.proximo
        return contador_fila

def imprimir_elemento(fila):
    if fila_vazia(fila):
        print("A fila está vazia\n")
    else:
        ver_pessoa = fila.inicio
        while ver_pessoa != None:
            print(ver_pessoa.nome, ver_pessoa.idade, ver_pessoa.peso, 
            ver_pessoa.genero, end=" " if ver_pessoa.proximo != None else print())
            ver_pessoa = ver_pessoa.proximo

fila_encadeada = Fila()
opcao = 1
while opcao != 6:
    print ("1 - Inserir")
    print ("2 - Excluir")
    print ("3 - Imprimir")
    print ("4 - Informar tamanho da fila")
    print ("5 - Informar se a fila está vazia")
    print ("6 - Sair")
    opcao = int(input("Informe a opção: "))
    if opcao == 1:
        nome_informado = str(input("Informe o nome da pessoa: "))
        idade_informada = int(input("Informe a idade de {}: ".format(nome_informado)))
        peso_informado = float(input("Informe o peso de {}: ".format(nome_informado)))
        genero_informado = str(input("Informe o gênero de {}: ".format(nome_informado)))
        novo_elemento = Pessoa()
        novo_elemento.nome = nome_informado
        novo_elemento.idade = idade_informada
        novo_elemento.peso = peso_informado
        novo_elemento.genero = genero_informado
        inserir_elemento(fila_encadeada, novo_elemento)
    elif opcao == 2:
        excluir_elemento(fila_encadeada)
    elif opcao == 3:
        imprimir_elemento(fila_encadeada)
    elif opcao == 4:
        print(f"Tamanho da Fila: {tamanho_fila(fila_encadeada)}\n")
    elif opcao == 5:
        if(fila_vazia(fila_encadeada) == True):
            print(f"A fila está vazia\n")
        else:
            print(f"A fila não está vazia e possui {tamanho_fila(fila_encadeada)} elemento(s)\n")
    elif opcao == 6:
        print("Saindo...\n")
    else:
        print("Opção inválida, digite uma opção válida no menu\n")
```

Comment: Pela convenção do nome de `Fila` e `Pessoas`, elas são classes. E pelo erro você não as definiu. Você tem certeza que não está pulando etapas para aprender Python? Caso queira aprender passo a passo, com calma, recomendo os vídeos do [Gustavo Guanabara, do Curso em Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/user/cursosemvideo/playlists).

Comment: Me parece que você está aprendendo muito aleatoriamente e está perdendo uns conceitos interessantes. Como por exemplo, [como identificar mensagens de erro](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). Ou em português na [Wiki](https://wiki.python.org.br/Tutorial_Python) (seção 8.3)

Comment: Onde estão os arquivos que contém o código do Fila() e Pessoas() ?

Comment: Não sei do que você está falando

Comment: O python não vem com nenhuma classe ou função chamadas `Fila()` ou `Pessoas()`, por isso é lançado um erro, pois o python não consegue identificar o que são essas classes. Se você criou estas classes é necessário importá-las no seu código para que você possa usá-las. Pesquise sobre `import` e depois que você entender, adicione os imports no seu código. Ficaria algo como `from meu_modulo import Fila, Pessoas`

Answer (score 8):

Acredito que não está importando a classe `Fila()` do modulo.

Ex:
`from <modulo onde está a classe> import Fila`

O seu erro se parece com esse, e está correto pois não declarei o modulo dá classe `Fila`

```
>>> filaencadeada = Fila()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Fila' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: É verdade, você deve importar sua classe para q ela seja vista por esse módulo. Outra coisa que você deve olhar e nas validações das opção, lembrando que os inputs sempre retornam ``` str``` é você está comparada como int, converts as entradas do usuário para interior ou faça as comparações como string.

Comment: Acho que ainda não entendi

Answer (score 8):

Dada a implementação, diria que uma lista já resolveria suficientemente bem o seu problema, não precisando implementar uma lista encadeada para tal, mas considerando que a lista encadeada faça parte do problema e deve ser implementada eu recomendo que você separe as responsabilidades.

O atributo `proximo` pertence ao nó de uma lista encadeada, não da pessoa, tanto que não faz sentido uma pessoa ter valor em `proximo` se ela não estiver em uma fila. A instância de `Pessoa` será apenas o valor armazenado no nó da fila, ela não deve ser o próprio nó.

Utilizando as dataclasses introduzidas no Python 3.6, você pode implementar a classe `Pessoa` da seguinte forma:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Pessoa:
    nome: str
    idade: int
    peso: float
    genero: str
```

Perceba que quando utilizado as dataclasses, você apenas precisa fazer as anotações dos tipos dos campos da sua classe, diferente do que você fez que foi definir **atributos de classes**; se não for trabalhar com dataclasses, recomendo que leia como trabalhar com **atributos de instância** e quais são as diferenças dela para as de classe.

Para implementar a lista encadeada, você precisará de duas classes: a nó, que representará cada item da lista, e a lista por si só. O nó só precisará de dois campos: o valor armazenado, que neste exemplo será uma pessoa, e uma referência ao nó posterior.

```
from typing import Any

@dataclass
class No:
    valor: Any
    proximo: 'No' = None
```

E para a lista em si poderia fazer algo como:

```
class Lista:
    def __init__(self):
        self.primeiro = None

    def inserir(self, no: No):
        if self.primeiro is None:
            self.primeiro = no
            return

        cursor = self.primeiro
        while cursor.proximo is not None:
            cursor = cursor.proximo
        cursor.proximo = no

    def __len__(self):
        if self.primeiro is None:
            return 0

        tamanho = 0
        cursor = self.primeiro
        while cursor.proximo is not None:
            cursor = cursor.proximo
            tamanho += 1
        return tamanho
```

Podendo completar com os métodos que necessita.

Comment: Cara por enquanto não estou usando nenhum tipo de importação em fila, por isso não entendo muito o que você fez

Comment: @AlexF. O que seria "importação em fila"?

Comment: esses `imports` de seu código, seria isso não?

Comment: @AlexF. Apenas importações de módulos nativos do Python

Answer (score 5):

### Formatação

Seu código não atende ao estilo sugerido pela [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Os programadores Python costumam usar a PEP 8 como um guia pra formatação do código. Eu recomendo fortemente que você refatore o seu código para atender a essas orientações. Por exemplo, a função `inserirElemento` se tornaria `inserir_elemento`.

### Orientação a objetos

Note que você fez uma separação clara entre dados e comportamento. Ao ler o seu código, nota-se que as classes descrevem dados, enquanto as funções descrevem comportamentos. Isso fica ainda mais claro se você observar que todas as tuas funções exigem uma instância da classe `Fila`.

Não há nada de errado em separar dados e comportamentos. Aliás, linguagens de paradigma declarativo geralmente privilegiam este tipo de abordagem. No entanto, no caso do Python, eu recomendo transformar essas funções em métodos das suas classes. (especialmente da classe `Fila`).

### Separação de responsabilidades

Quando se está criando um programa de computador, os elementos do código geralmente podem ser divididos em categorias. Ao ler o seu programa, identifico três categorias:

1. Negócio: Elementos responsáveis por representar o domínio do problema que você está resolvendo.
2. Mecanismo: Elementos responsáveis por modificar e alterar dados de maneira genérica e reutilizável.
3. Apresentação: Elementos responsáveis por se comunicar com o mundo exterior.

Exemplos:

- Aquele `while` com um monte de `if`s é um elemento de apresentação.
- A classe `Pessoa` é um elemento de negócio.
- A classe `Fila` é um mecanismo.

Você deve organizar o seu código de modo que os elementos de cada categoria não se misturem, apenas se relacionem e se encaixem, como se fossem pecinhas de lego.

Veja essa função aqui, por exemplo:

```py
def imprimirElemento(fila):
    if filaVazia(fila):
        print("A fila está vazia\n")
    else:
        verPessoa = fila.inicio
        while verPessoa != None:
            print(verPessoa.nome, verPessoa.idade, verPessoa.peso, 
            verPessoa.genero, end=" "if verPessoa.proxima != None else print())
            verPessoa = verPessoa.proxima
```

Essa função imprime dados na tela (apresentação), itera por uma fila (mecanismo) e formata os dados da pessoa (negócio).

Se você mudar a implementação da fila, essa função vai quebrar. Se você mudar a implementação da pessoa, essa função vai quebrar. Se você mudar a forma como os dados são exibidos, essa função vai quebrar. Ou seja, essa função é um emaranhado de responsabilidades. Você deve *separar* estas responsabilidades.

Há vários livros sobre este assunto. Caso queira se aprofundar, pode começar por *Object-Oriented Reengineering Patterns*.

### Exemplos de implementação

Vou dar dois exemplos de implementação: Classes `Fila` e `Pessoa`.

Lembre-se que a fila é um mecanismo. Você sabe de antemão que precisará usar uma fila, e sabe quais operações essa fila terá que realizar. A fila deve ser genérica e sem qualquer dependência das classes de negócio. Em outras palavras, crie essa classe tendo em mente que você deve ser capaz de reutilizá-la em qualquer programa que precise de uma fila.

```py
class Nodo():
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
        self.proximo = None

class Fila():
    def __init__(self):
        self.primeiro = None
        self.ultimo = None
        self.contador = 0

    def enfileirar(self, valor):
        novo = Nodo(valor)

        if self:
            self.ultimo.proximo = novo
        else:
            self.primeiro = novo

        self.ultimo = novo
        self.contador += 1

    def desenfileirar(self):
        if not self:
            raise IndexError()

        primeiro = self.primeiro

        if primeiro == self.ultimo:
            self.ultimo = None
            self.primeiro = None
        else:
            self.primeiro = primeiro.proximo

        self.contador -= 1

        return primeiro.valor

    def __len__(self):
        return self.contador

    def __bool__(self):
        return len(self) > 0

    def __iter__(self):
        temp = self.primeiro

        while temp:
            yield temp.valor
            temp = temp.proximo
```

Perceba que todas as operações foram definidas dentro da classe `Fila`. Ela é totalmente autocontida.

A classe `Pessoa` deve ser responsável não apenas por guardar os dados da pessoa, mas também por conter todos os comportamentos esperados de uma pessoa. No caso do domínio do seu problema, identifico que os comportamentos são:

- Gerar uma representação textual da pessoa
- Decidir se duas instâncias representam a mesma pessoa no mundo real

Note que não é responsabilidade desta classe printar coisas no terminal.

```py
class Pessoa():
    def __init__(self, nome, idade, peso, genero):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade
        self.peso = peso
        self.genero = genero

    def __eq__(self, outro):
        if not isinstance(outro, type(self)):
            return False

        return (
            self.nome == outro.nome and
            self.idade == outro.idade and
            self.peso == outro.peso and
            self.genero == outro.genero
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Nome: {self.nome}; Idade: {self.idade}; Peso: {self.peso}; Gênero: {self.genero}'
```

Veja que esta forma de implementação permite que você teste cada pedaço do código isoladamente. Isso é muito, muito importante em sistemas mais complexos, e você deve obter desde já o costume de criar códigos facilmente testáveis.

### Respondendo a sua dúvida

> Eu queria saber como fazer com que esse código em fila permita que haja uma verificação se um nome específico do elemento está na fila

Você pode criar uma função pra isso.

```py
def procurar_por_nome(fila, nome_procurado):
    for pessoa in fila:
        if pessoa.nome == nome_procurado:
            return pessoa

    return None

fila = Fila()

fila.enfileirar(Pessoa('Bianca', 24, 50, 'F'))
fila.enfileirar(Pessoa('Jéssica', 28, 54, 'F'))
fila.enfileirar(Pessoa('Maisa', 22, 44, 'F'))
fila.enfileirar(Pessoa('Tatiane', 34, 55, 'F'))

nome_procurado = input('Nome: ')

pessoa = procurar_por_nome(fila, nome_procurado)

if pessoa:
    print(pessoa)
else:
    print('Pessoa não encontrada')
```

(Perceba que eu utilizei as classes que sugeri)

No entanto, seria muito melhor se você criasse um método de busca na própria classe `Fila` que recebe um predicado e retorna o primeiro elemento que atende ao predicado.

```py
class Fila():
    # ... outros métodos que já mostrei...

    def encontrar(self, predicado):
        for item in self:
            if predicado(item):
                return item

        return None
```

Agora você pode usar este método pra encontrar uma pessoa sob qualquer critério, não apenas por nome.

```py
nome_procurado = input('Nome: ')

pessoa = fila.encontrar(lambda pessoa: pessoa.nome == nome_procurado)

if pessoa:
    print(pessoa)
else:
    print('Pessoa não encontrada')
```

### Observação

Há muitas melhorias a serem feitas no código que eu sugeri. A minha intenção não era mostrar um código perfeito, mas sim abrir seus olhos pra outras formas de abordar o problema.

Comment: Uma dúvida sobre **respondendo a sua dúvida** é preciso criar um `def` para isso?

Comment: @AlexF. Eu reescrevi essa parte pra tornar mais claro.

Comment: Não deu certo..

Answer (score 4):

Ao criar classes é uma boa prática começar com letra maiúscula `class Pessoa`, todo método de uma classe que faça parte da instancia(métodos não estáticos) devem ter como primeiro parâmetro `self`, alguns de seus métodos estão faltando isso, propriedades da classe também devem ter o `self` e devem estar dentro do método `__init__`, a classe `Pessoa` estar faltando o método `__init__` coloque aqueles atributos dentro dela, existe alguns erros como `pessoa.fila = []` nesse comando você esta acessando a propriedade que a classe `Pessoa` tem mas na sua implementação a classe não possui essa propriedade, há outro também nessa parte `print (fila.excluirElemento())` onde você usa a variável `fila` que nem mesmo foi definida, dê uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176543/por-que-temos-que-utilizar-o-atributo-self-como-argumento-nos-m%C3%A9todos) sobre como usar o `self`

*Classe `Pessoa`(implementação recomendada)*

```py
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade, peso, genero):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade
        self.peso = peso
        self.genero = genero


davi = Pessoa("Davi", 27, 89, 1)
```

Comment: a classe `fila` tá certa?

Comment: como eu falei na resposta, vc esqueceu de colocar o `self` nos métodos e ta usando um atributo da classe Pessoa que não existe que no caso é `pessoa.fila` sua implementação da classe Pessoa não tem o atributo `fila`