# Retorno inesperado do método

Tags: python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Estou aprendendo POO em python, eu criei uma classe cliente que possui três atributos; nome, cpf e idade. E criei também um método que guarda esses atributos dentro de uma tupla e retorna essa tupla. Porém o método não retornou a tupla, ele retornou isso:

```
<bound method Cliente.dados of <__main__.Cliente object at 0x7f8788c67940>>
```

Não consigo entender o porque disso.

**Método:**

```
def dados():
        """
        método criado para retornar todos os dados em uma tupla
        """
        dados = (self.nome,self.idade,self.cpf)
        return dados
```

**Instância**

```
clientes = Cliente('Joaquin',21,'04040505')

print(clientes.dados)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro o corre porque você ta tentando da um `print` na função em vez de tu chamar ela

o correto seria

```
clientes = Cliente('Joaquin',21,'04040505')

print(clientes.dados())
```

outra coisa sua função dados esta errada, acredito que no código esteja correta, mas faltou um paramento, que por convenção deve ser passado sempre que se criar um método/função o `self.

```
def dados(self):
        """
        método criado para retornar todos os dados em uma tupla
        """
        dados = (self.nome,self.idade,self.cpf)
        return dados
```

pode se informar melhor nessa resposta no [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130574/bound-method-error/32873257)

Comment: Deu certo agora, mas porque eu tenho que colocar o self como parâmetro?

Comment: @eudsonduraes https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176543/112052

Comment: Cara, é mas uma convenção, não é obrigatório. corrigir na resposta, mas é para dizer que ele pertence a uma classe, nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176543/por-que-temos-que-utilizar-o-atributo-self-como-argumento-nos-m%C3%A9todos) explica bem

Comment: Na verdade, se é um método sempre deverá existir um primeiro parâmetro que será referência para a própria instância; apenas o nome `self` que é convenção.