# Necessidade de declarar um atributo no __init__

Tags: python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

eu estava fazendo um Dado em python3, até aí tudo bem. porém eu não entendo o porquê que preciso colocar os atributos no **init**, sendo que tendo eles ou não vai funcionar da "mesma forma" e não consigo ver um "sentido".

Eu aprendi Orientação a Objetos com Java e lá realmente as coisas fazem mais sentido ou eu que não estou entendendo. A Orientação a Objetos do Python é um pouco confusa para mim.

Perdão pela forma que estou me expressando/escrevendo, talvez pareça grosseiro.

```
class Dado(object):
    def __init__(self, cor="vermelho", lado=6):
      self._cor = cor

    def setCor(self, cor):
      self._cor = cor


     def getCor(self):
      return self._cor
```

ou

```
class Dado(object):
    def __init__(self):
      pass

    def setCor(self, cor):
      self._cor = cor

    def getCor(self):
      return self._cor
```

Por que eu preciso declarar um atributo no **init**? ou por que isso é necessário?

Tipo, funciona das 2 formas.

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Por que eu preciso declarar um atributo no __init__? ou por que isso é necessário?
Tipo, funciona das 2 formas.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que temos que utilizar o atributo self como argumento nos métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176543/por-que-temos-que-utilizar-o-atributo-self-como-argumento-nos-m%c3%a9todos)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma regra escrita que você deve declarar as regras em seu **init**()
É apenas uma questão de convenção.
Quando você declara as variáveis no init é o equivalente a declarar suas variáveis no construtor.
Sobre a sua pergunta:

```
Por que eu preciso declarar um atributo no init? ou por que isso é necessário?
```

Não é necessário declarar um atributo no init. Não é necessário. Tudo funciona normal.
Isso serve apenas como um atalho para criar uma instancia de sua classe de uma maneira mais declarativa, ou até mesmo de setar valores padrão na inicialização da classe.

O equivalente a esta declaração que você fez em python em java seria:

```
//classe
class Dado {
     private String cor;
     private int lado;
     //construtor padrão do java não precisa ser declarado sempre vai existir 
     //public Dado(){
     //}
     //construtor 2
     public Dado(String cor, int lado) {
         this.cor = cor == null ? "vermelho" : cor;
         this.lado = lado == 0 ? 6 : lado
     }
     //getters e setters
}
```

Porém gostaria de destacar que não é necessário ter o segundo construtor, pois sempre teremos o construtor padrão do java, sem parâmetros.
O fato de declarar uma variável no método init é equivalente ao fato de declarar uma variável no construtor do java. Apenas isso mas o construtor não é obrigatório, tudo funciona normal sem declara variáveis no construtor.