# Django. Não consigo passar o modelo que eu gostaria por meio de classes

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, django

Eu estou tendo um problema em criar uma página para criar novos produtos e sei que estou tendo algum problema com *oop* por falta de experiência. Eu gostaria de passar o valor de `self` neste caso sendo `self==Product`, mas acabou passando `self==Creat_view` e não sei o que estou fazendo de errado. (a indentação das classes estão corretas no programa(-1 tab), só o código que não cola direito aqui)

```
form_class_mapping = {'Product':ProductModelForm,'Gondola':ProdGondolaModelForm,'Stock':ProdStockModelForm}
```

```
class List_view(ListView):
    template_name ='templates/list.html'

    def __init__(self):
        print(self)
        queryset = self.objects.all()


class Creat_view(CreateView):
    template_name ='templates/create.html'

    def __init__(self):
        queryset = self.objects.all()
        self.form_class = form_class_mapping[self]

    def form_valid(self,form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Aqui estão minhas urls:

```
    app_name = 'Product'
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', List_view.as_view(),name="Product-list"),
    path('create/', Creat_view.as_view(),name="Product-create"),
    path('<int:id>/update/', Update_view.as_view(),name="Product-update"),
    path('<int:id>/delete/', Delete_view.as_view(),name="Product-delete")
    
    ]
```

E meu erro é:

```
    File "C:\Users\user\dev\cms\sgi\StockManagement\views.py", line 22, in __init__
    queryset = self.objects.all()
    AttributeError: 'Creat_view' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Edit:
Eu consigo fazer funcionar caso eu mude meu código para (abaixo), mas gostaria de usar essa classe para outros modelos além de Product

```
class Creat_view(CreateView):
    template_name ='templates/create.html'

    def __init__(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        form_class = ProductModelForm

    def form_valid(self,form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que temos que utilizar o atributo self como argumento nos métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176543/por-que-temos-que-utilizar-o-atributo-self-como-argumento-nos-m%c3%a9todos)

Comment: Isso me ajudou a entender o argumento self, mas eu ainda não sei como resolver meu problema. Eu consigo fazer funcionar se eu mudar como adicionei na edição, mas eu gostaria de usar essa classe para acessar outros modelos além de Product e não sei como passar o argumento para dentro da função sem um erro que o numero de argumentos está errado.

Comment: Coloca isso o que você acabou de explicar na pergunta, é esclarecedor. PS: peço porque  formato do site que exige que as informações relevantes devam estar contidos na pergunta, os [comentários são só um meio descartável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3814/%C3%89-possivel-saber-o-motivo-de-terem-deletado-removido-os-meus-coment%C3%A1rios-de-uma) para aprimorar as perguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Após algum tempo tentando resolver eu finalmente consegui

```
form_class_mapping = {'Product':ProductModelForm,'Gondola':ProdGondolaModelForm,'Stock':ProdStockModelForm}
queryset_mapping = {'Product':Product,'Gondola':Product_Gondola,'Stock':Product_Stock}
class List_view(ListView):
    template_name ='templates/list.html'
    form_class = 0
    queryset = 0

    @classmethod
    def Argument(cls,*arg):
        cls.form_class = form_class_mapping[arg[0]]
        cls.queryset =  queryset_mapping[arg[0]].objects.all()


class Creat_view(CreateView):
    template_name ='templates/create.html'
    form_class = 0
    queryset = 0

    @classmethod
    def Argument(cls,*arg):
        cls.form_class = form_class_mapping[arg[0]]
        cls.queryset =  queryset_mapping[arg[0]].objects.all()

    def form_valid(self,form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

as urls:

```
app_name = 'Product'

List_view.Argument(app_name)
Creat_view.Argument(app_name)
Update_view.Argument(app_name)
Delete_view.Argument(app_name)

print(List_view.__dict__)
urlpatterns = [
    path('', List_view.as_view(),name="Product-list"),
    path('create/', Creat_view.as_view(),name="Product-create"),
    path('<int:id>/update/', Update_view.as_view(),name="Product-update"),
    path('<int:id>/delete/', Delete_view.as_view(),name="Product-delete")
```