# Qual é a diferença entre "this" e "self" em python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Olá, estava resolvendo umas questões em python quando observei o uso de `self` em uma classe. Fiquei em dúvida nisso porque sempre usei o `this`. Então fiz esses pequenos códigos para tentar entender mais sobre o assunto:

```
class Test():
  def __init__(this):
    this.message = 'Hello World'

test = Test()
print(test.message)
```

E o outro código:

```
class Test():
  def __init__(self):
    self.message = 'Hello World'

test = Test()
print(test.message)
```

A única coisa que muda entre os dois é a troca do `this` pelo `self`, no segundo código. E curiosamente, os dois tiveram os mesmos resultados.
Resumindo, existe alguma diferença entre `self` e `this`? Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode nomear a variavel de foobar que ainda vai funcionar, self é usado por convenção, é só um nome que se dá, o nome self não tem absolutamente nenhum significado especial para Python. Observe, no entanto, que, ao não seguir a convenção, seu código pode ser menos legível para outros programadores Python, e também é concebível que um programa de navegador de classe possa ser escrito com base em tal convenção. Conforme documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Apesar do link indicado acima no box azul não ter um título que sugira que é a mesma coisa que vc perguntou, [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/183747/112052) de lá explica isso: "*`self` é uma convenção que todo bom pythonista segue, mas na verdade você poderia colocar o que quisesse de nome do primeiro parâmetro do método, `this`, `obj`, `abobrinha`*"

Comment: inclusive, completando o qu eo @hkotsubo comentou, *this* e *self* nem são palavras reservadas da linguagem até onde eu sei

Comment: @RicardoPontual De fato não são mesmo: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

Comment: @hkotsubo legal ter encontrado o link, removi a resposta, agora fica um bom exemplo de uso de pergunta dup. Obrigado!

Comment: @RicardoPontual um ótimo adendo mencionar a questão dos palavras, e também obrigado ao hkotsubo por trazer o link.